# How to fix if statement in my def function

Tags: python, if-statement

I write code.

if statement in function def.

i don't know why the answer always "yes"

suppose we type "n"

```
a = input('''Yes or No, Type [Y/N]''')

def test():
   global a
   if a == 'Y' or 'y':
      print("yes")
   elif a == 'N' or 'n':
    print("no")
   else:
    print("Not Yes and Not No")

test()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: `if a == 'Y' or a=='y':`

Comment: thank you -Tushar your answer helped me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it much simpler by making it not case sensitive

```
a = input('Yes or No Type [Y/N]')

def test():

    global a

    if a.lower() == 'y': #this will convert the string into lower case

        print("yes")

    elif a.lower() == 'n':

        print("no")

    else:

        print("Not Yes and Not No")

test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to make it more robust:

```
yes = ['Y' , 'y' , 'yes' , 'YES', 'Yes']
no = ['N' , 'n' , 'NO', 'No', 'no']

if answer in yes:
    print("yes")

if answer in no:
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yes = ['y', 'yes']
no = ['n', 'no']

if answer.lower() in yes:
    print("yes")

if answer.lower() in no:
    print("no")
```